# WebView loadDataWithBaseURL on finished loading listener

Tags: java, android, webview

I'm loading data in a webview using loadDataWithBaseURL from a string. I want to implement a listener which tells me when the data is loaded completely so that i may proceed with my code.

I've searched a lot but could not find any relevant topic

```
if (new String(rowData.getResource().getData()) != null) webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", new String(rowData.getResource().getData()), "text/html", "UTF-8", "about:blank");
```

Answer (score 2):

Use WebViewClient and implement onPageStarted,onPageFinished to know the status of the webview.

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog.show(this);
progressDialog.setMessage("Loading WebPage...");

class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
    }

}

webview.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
```

Comment: can you plz write a little sample which i can modify.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Tested working demo.

```
public class URLActivity extends Activity {

    private ProgressDialog progress;

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview);

        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setInitialScale(0);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);

        webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", new String(rowData.getResource().getData()), "text/html", "UTF-8", "about:blank");

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
                super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
                if (newProgress > 0) {
                    showProgressDialog("Please Wait");
                }
                if (newProgress >= 100) {
                    hideProgressDialog();

                    // data load successfully. you can go further.
                }
            }
        });

    }

    public void showProgressDialog(final String msg) {

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (progress == null || !progress.isShowing()) {
                    progress = ProgressDialog.show(URLActivity.this, "", msg);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void hideProgressDialog() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    if (progress.isShowing())
                        progress.dismiss();
                } catch (Throwable e) {

                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: i have tried this but the code proceeds even when the loading is in progress.